# trying to change the text of the button without editing the html code

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the text of the button without editing the HTML code but it doesn't really work

Here is the code:

```
document.querySelector(".game-button").onClick = function knop(knop) {
    document.querySelector(".game-button").innerHTML = "Reset spel";
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="game-button">Start spel</button>
```

Comment: Why not using `addEventListener` and then use `this.innerHTML` inside it to update the HTML of the clicked element.

Comment: It should be `.onclick`, not `onClick`. ;-)

Comment: and also thanks for the addEventListener Tip

Comment: Yes, programming that thing where one character really counts.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest:

```
var gameButton = document.querySelector(".game-button")
gameButton.onclick = function() {
    gameButton.innerHTML = "Reset spel";
}
```

I've put the gamebutton in a variable so it is only referenced once.
Since this is a function connected to an onclick event, naming the function is not needed. Also, you are not passing or using any arguments, so there is no need to put anything between the ().

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
document.querySelector(".game-button").onClick = function knop() {
    this.innerHTML = "Reset spel";
}
```